# Restore(?) generic USB keyboard driver from command line in repair-mode

Tags: windows-7, command-line, keyboard, mouse, windows-7-restore

As the title says, I'm experiencing some troubles with a dead keyboard (and mouse, for that sake) at the Windows 7 (enterprise) login screen, and I can't find a way to fix it.

Earlier today I decided to let Windows install some system updates; after the following reboot both keyboard and mouse won't work at the login screen. If I remember correctly, rebooting was optional, so possible the updates weren't of the kind that requires you to reboot, however, I can't say this for sure.

When trying to boot into safe-mode, I struggle with the same; I don't get any further than the login-screen. I managed to enter repair-mode, and here both keyboard and mouse work fine. This, both with and without a Windows installation device. Hence, I suspect the problem is related to the drivers for the two in some way.

Unfortunately for me, I don't have any restoration point, and of course Windows can't find any problems to repair, so I'm kinda stuck.

I've tried replacing the registry (SYSTEM-part, at least) by copying a backup from *System32\config\RegBack*, but this didn't work.

Running **sfc /scannow** returns an message saying that a system-repair is pending and that Windows needs to reboot before running it.

Any suggestions to localize the error? E.g., any specific commands or files I can check to localize what changes that were made during the update? Or maybe it's possible to uninstall updates while in repair-mode?

If it's related to the drivers of the keyboard/mouse; is it possible to copy these from a Win7 installation media and replace those that Windows is loading during startup, or something like that?

Comment: You cannot simply type in `sfc /scannow` while booted into WinRE, since that syntax by default, applies to the running version of Windows which would be WinRE not your actual installation.

Comment: Well, you can type it, but as mentioned it doesn't get you anywhere, as I wrote. But I wasn't clear of that fact before trying. Anyways, any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Ended up formatting as it took less time than to figure out what was wrong, so question can be marked as answered/closed, or deleted. Doesn't really matter for me.